# Strange issue with indexing on Neo4j 2.0 server

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a Neo4j server into which I imported 600k+ Person nodes from a csv. Each node has the following properties

```
userid, username, email, firstname, lastname, age
```

Before importing, I set up the following constraints...

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) assert p.userid is unique
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) assert p.username is unique
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) assert p.email is unique
```

The import seemed to go well and I decided to run the following Cypher statements to verify some data

```
MATCH (p:Person{userid:8423}) return p
MATCH (p:Person{username:"jomski2009"}) return p
```

The first query correctly returned the result expected. However, running the second query return an empty result. I can verify that the username does indeed exist as its supposed to be the same object returned by both queries.

I have tried dropping and recreating the username constraint and yet no change. What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT: I attached a screenshot of the result when I match on userid. Matching on the username displayed just does not work.

[image: Screenshot of the result of a match on userid]

Comment: That's what I would expect: the presence or absence of an index should have no effect on the result set, only on the speed of the query. Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere?

Comment: @Bossie I've checked and double checked the query, both in the consoles and in code. Its quite baffling. Querying with any parameter other than the userid just returns 0 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have no typos?

Already in this question, you use the userid 8432 once and once 8423 ?

I tried your constraints and creating and matching and it worked for me.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.userid IS UNIQUE
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.username IS UNIQUE

CREATE (p:Person { userid:8423,username:"jomski2009" }) RETURN p
-> {userid:8423, username:"jomski2009"}

MATCH (p:Person { userid:8423 }) RETURN p
-> {userid:8423, username:"jomski2009"}

MATCH (p:Person { username:"jomski2009" }) RETURN p
-> {userid:8423, username:"jomski2009"}
```

Can you please try the exactly same steps?

Comment: Whoops!! I think I now see what happened. When I imported the csv data, my code inadevertently added quotes around the string data which got stored in Neo4j. So matching on jomski2009 yielded not result, however matching on "jomski2009" worked.... Looks like I have to scrub my data and re-import. Running the steps was what showed up the difference. Thanks. BTW, is there a way to iterate through the nodes and trim out the excess quotes?